# Why Android throws NullPointerException?

Tags: android, arrays, setting

I wrote a PreferenceActivity, its setting.xml includes the following code:

```
        <ListPreference 
     android:key="key"
     android:title="@string/title"
     android:entries="@array/entries"
     android:entryValues="@array/values">        
    </ListPreference>
```

And I supply the following in array.xml

```
<array name="entries"><item>displayName</item></array>
<array name="values"><item>10240</item></array>
```

When the <item> is 10240, Android will throw NullPointerException. But when I changes it to 10240k, Android will work.Why？

Answer (score 1):

Try a `<string-array>` instead.

Comment: thank you.It works.But why <array> won't work?It is strange to me.

Comment: <array> doesn't work in that case because it sees 10240 as an integer